# What is the group and count ActiveRecord query returning on the right side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out what this query is returning:

```
 @themes = Theme.joins({submissions: [:digitization]}).group('themes.id').count
 => {1=>15, 5=>1, 7=>1, 10=>1, 11=>1, 13=>69, 14=>4, 17=>2, 18=>4, 19=>2, 20=>1, 22=>1, 31=>91, 32=>118, 33=>102, 34=>156, 35=>84, 36=>82, 37=>130, 38=>116, 39=>86, 40=>117, 41=>89, 42=>138, 43=>120, 44=>146, 45=>63, 46=>92, 47=>122, 48=>62, 49=>151, 50=>91, 51=>172, 52=>72, 53=>94, 54=>120, 55=>136, 56=>80, 57=>137,
```

What is the value on the right side? What is the value on the left side? I know we're grouping by `themes.id` and so I can see the left side being the id of the theme.... but what is the count on the right side?

Here's the sql:

```
 @themes = Theme.joins({submissions: [:digitization]}).group('themes.id').to_sql
 => "SELECT `themes`.* FROM `themes` INNER JOIN `submissions` ON `submissions`.`theme_id` = `themes`.`id` AND (purchase_status = \"Complete\" or purchase_status = \"Purchased\") INNER JOIN `digitizations` ON `digitizations`.`submission_code` = `submissions`.`identifier` GROUP BY themes.id"
```

I know the `joins` are doing inner joins and are only returning `themes` were there exists a `digitization` (found through the `theme`'s `submissions`)

Comment: I think (and I might be wrong) that the hash is like `theme_id => themes' count`. The `Theme` with id `13` should have 69 submissions (you can check with `Theme.find(13).submissions.count`)

Comment: Oh it's not the digitization?

Comment: If a single `Theme` has 2 `Submission` associated, then `Theme.joins(:submissions)` will return the same `Theme` record twice. Having another level of join will probably duplicate the `Submission` records and therefore the `Theme` too, so yes this is probably the `digitalization` count, but I am not sure. You have to try it on your side and double check the results

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the count of 'digitization'. I have tested it myself using the above query and also manually checking the counts.

Answer (score 1):

The count of the right side is the **size of each group that is formed after grouping on the basis of themes.id**

For example, let us say there forms 2 groups, 1st for theme.id = 1 and 2nd for theme.id = 2.
First group has 2 members and 2nd group has 3 members.

Then the above query will return

```
=> {1=>2, 2=>3}
```

The value on the right side is the count of 'digitization' that corresponds the theme.id to the left.